# Phonegap inappbrowser manage before loadstart

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm creating a simple app with phonegap, it's a browser that it can only open a specific domain. to manage that I'm using InAppBrowser.

Now, what I have is the following:

on onDeviceReady method I open the main domain I wanna show in the app

```html
var browser = window.open('example.com', '_self');
```

Then I add the method loadstart like this:

```html
browser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e){
  //if the url is different as the main domain
  if(e.url.indexOf('example.com') === -1){
    //open the url in default browser
    navigator.app.loadUrl(e.url, { openExternal:true });
  }
});
```

But the problem is that my app is also loading that new url so I would need something like 'beforeloading' method where I could check the url to be loaded like I do in 'loadstart' method.

I already tried to stop the default behaviour whit this e.preventDefault(); but I guess that the event which handle the loading page is previous than the 'loadstart' method.

Any idea to be able to achieve what I need?

thanks in advance :)